# Is it possible to Parse this XML file using SQL Server or SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, ssis

I have an XML file I receive from a financial data provider called MDM. It shows which dividends I have downloaded. It includes information like Dividend rate, date and the security requested.

I have tried to parse this with SSIS using the XML source and Merge Join. I also tried SQL Server 2012 using Open XML and couldn't do it. I gathered these techniques from Youtube, google and searching this board. My goal is for this to be in an easy to read table format so I can see which securities received dividend information.

When I tried to Parse it with SSIS the following output names were given

```
FIELD
SECURITY
APP_PARAM
MDM_MESSAGE
```

The XML file is too big to post entirely here but I have included a Dropbox link that hopefully works. Hopefully someone can help. I am not sure if this file, though XML can be parsed or not.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29851290/parse_file.xml

Ideally the output will be something like this.

```
SYM_TYPE_ID   SEC_SYMBOL  SEC_TYPE_ID FOR DATE    EX_DT    PAY_DT     WASH_AMOUNT      RATE TICKER           
aapl          csus        (Not sure)  5/15/2013   6/1/2013 (Not Sure)    0.25
```

Comment: What information (which nodes, which attributes) do you need to extract from this XML?

Comment: I would like to get SYM_TYPE_ID, SEC_SYMBOL, SEC_TYPE_ID, FOR DATE, EX_DT, PAY_DT, WASH_AMOUNT, RATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = CONVERT (XML, [BulkColumn])
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N'C:\parse_file.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) [XmlData]

SELECT PROV_ID = t.c.value('../@PROV_ID', 'VARCHAR(25)') 
     , SYM_TYPE_ID = t.c.value('../@SYM_TYPE_ID', 'VARCHAR(25)')
     , SEC_SYMBOL = t.c.value('../@SEC_SYMBOL', 'VARCHAR(25)')
     , SEC_TYPE_ID = t.c.value('../@SEC_TYPE_ID', 'VARCHAR(25)')
     , LOCAL_NAME = t.c.value('@LOCAL_NAME', 'VARCHAR(25)')
     , FOR_DATE = t.c.value('@FOR_DATE', 'DATETIME')
     , FIELD = t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(25)')
FROM @XML.nodes('root/MDM_MESSAGE[2]/SECURITY/FIELD') t(c)
WHERE t.c.value('@SEC_SYMBOL', 'VARCHAR(25)') = '57636Q104'

UNION ALL

SELECT PROV_ID = t.c.value('@PROV_ID', 'VARCHAR(25)') 
     , SYM_TYPE_ID = t.c.value('@SYM_TYPE_ID', 'VARCHAR(25)')
     , SEC_SYMBOL = t.c.value('@SEC_SYMBOL', 'VARCHAR(25)')
     , SEC_TYPE_ID = t.c.value('@SEC_TYPE_ID', 'VARCHAR(25)')
     , LOCAL_NAME = NULL
     , FOR_DATE = NULL
     , FIELD = NULL
FROM @XML.nodes('root/MDM_MESSAGE[2]/SECURITY') t(c)
WHERE t.c.exist('FIELD') = 0
     AND t.c.value('@SEC_SYMBOL', 'VARCHAR(25)') = '57636Q104'
```

Comment: This comes close but it ends up running 2 separate queries, with two separate grid result sets. Also how would I point it to a saved xml file rather than having the entire contents of the file in the query? I tried changing this line SELECT @XML = 'c:\xmlfiles\parse_file.xml' but that didn't work.

Comment: If I remove the first select statement it seems to work ok. I just keep the subsequent two combined through union. I still would like to point it to an actual xml file if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Devart, thanks this works and is very helpful. One last question. How could I add a where clause to be more selective for the given fields? For example I tried WHERE t.c.exist('FIELD') = 0
and SEC_Symbol = '57636Q104' but that didn't work?

Comment: Nice it works. One last question. How did you build this query? Is there a development tool out there that helped you construct it or did you write the whole thing by just looking at the xml file? I've marked the question as answered.

Comment: I use [dbForge Studio for MS-SQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/) that suits my needs the most and allows to solve all my professional tasks.

Comment: You're welcome @Jay C. I hope that I have answered on all your question.